# How do I use Quokka with imported typescript files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, quokka.js

I've installed ts-node with NPM install, and tinkered with this for hours, I cant find any other documentation on the website as to why its not working. A quick google search has also turned up nothing; which is why I'm SURE its some small thing I'm missing. ts-node has also been installed globally AND in the project folder I'm getting the following error:

```
To import TypeScript files from quokka, `ts-node` module must be installed. 
It is also recommended to install `tsconfig-paths` module for tsconfig.json paths mapping. 
You may install the modules in your project or into quokka global folder by running `npm install ts-node tsconfig-paths` command inside the `~/.quokka/` folder. 
  at ​​​Module.load​​​ ​internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653​
  at ​​​tryModuleLoad​​​ ​internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593​
  at ​​​Function.Module._load​​​ ​internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585​
  at ​​​require​​​ ​internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25​
  at ​​​Object.<anonymous>​​​ ​frontEnd/datrix/src/app/Logic/DeveloperTemplate.ts:1​
  at ​​​Module._compile​​​ ​internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778​
```

does anyone have some insight on how this can be done?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, I had to open the project file in vs code, not the directory above it.